# R quantmod: Connection error when pulling data

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to pull some stock quotes for Amazon via quantmod.  I just downloaded the package for the first time and am using R x64 3.5.3.  When I run this code:

```
library(quantmod)
amzn = getSymbols("AMZN",auto.assign=FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Can't replicate the issue when I use above code. Try using a clean R session.

Comment: @phiver I get the same error when I use a clean session.  When I run the same code on my home computer it works.